# Could a desktop application disclose location even if a VPN is used?

Tags: network, privacy, vpn, geolocation

When using a proper VPN to access a remote server, the server should not be able to resolve your country of origin using your IP address because the IP provided in the request will be the one of the proxy.

Now let's talk about a desktop application able to run system commands: even if you use a proxy to hide your origin country, could the malicious application perform a traceroute and provide the output to the remote server, allowing it to resolve your origin country?

Traceroute was the first example coming to my mind. Any other tool/technique proving the point could be used to answer the question (except locales about languages/keyboards/etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that it depends on how the VPN is set up. If truely all network traffic passes through the proxy, then the computer only knows the outside world through the proxy.

But there are many ways for traffic to not go through the proxy, and indeed, the application might attempt to bypass the proxy.

Comment: "all network traffic passes through the proxy" : shouldn't a traceroute provide the complete list of each physical/virtual relay it goes through, no matter if it's inside or outside the VPN ?

Comment: not usually any hops *within* a VPN circuit

Answer (score 5):

As you noted, "languages/keyboards" may help.

But it can be improved with "TimeZone"

Also, if the application has enough privilege, it may:

- Ask the operating system what is the location
- Ask the list of Wifi in range and if any one of them have a known location
- If it can read your personal files it may - for example - reads pictures location metadata.

More complicated but feasible:
- If it can reads the host file, it may use domains with known geoip DNS to detect where the computer was before using the VPN

Recent example - on android: an application without the "location" privilege (nor the "picture" one, but irrelevant here) could take a picture and reads it's metadata to locate the user. So a VPN would be useless if the phone OS had register an accurate position using GPS or Wifi: https://www.checkmarx.com/blog/how-attackers-could-hijack-your-android-camera

Answer (score 1):

```
a desktop application able to run system commands
```

All bets are off at this point. A malicious application could easily retrieve your real IP address and send it over the VPN to its C2 server. Or your local timezone. Or your locale settings such as language, date format, fonts...

Comment: But what is a "real IP"? The 192.168.1.102 address to your livingroom router isn't helpful. Does admin on my laptop have a way to know what external ISP IP the VPN is seeing from me? Is there another IP that admin has access to?

Comment: If you only _ever_ connected to the internet via a full-tunnelling VPN then maybe. But a malicious app is free to gather information at any other time.

Comment: "gather information at any other time" or read system (or other apps) logs.